# How to list ecs tasks using boto3 client when launch type is Fargate?

Tags: boto3, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to get list of task arns from a cluster (launch type Fargate) using boto3 client.

If launch type is EC2 then this works:

```
ecs = boto3.client('ecs')
ecs.list_tasks(
    cluster='cluster_name',
    containerInstance='container_instance_arn',
)
```

But when launch type is fargate there are no container instances to give to the function.
I tried with only cluster name

```
ecs = boto3.client('ecs')
ecs.list_tasks(
    cluster='cluster_name'
)
```

but it then fails to `“not authorized to perform: ecs:ListTasks on resource: *”`

When I use ECS API directly only cluster name is required. (launch type is Fargate)

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster <cluster_name>

{
    "taskArns": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:task/679ac0fa-107b-4e7c-b630-9d8ae3a1cb8b",
        "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:task/8abe5ea2-6323-46fd-b937-c976f273e517",
        "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:task/98c4e42b-a6a9-4353-b5b9-9ba78f116aa0"
    ]
}
```

How would I get this same list using boto3?

Edit: Here is a sample policy that I use:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecs:ListTasks",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ecs:*:xxxxxxxxxxx:container-instance/*",
                "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:log-group:/aws/lambda/aTestFunction:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message told the answer directly.

```
“not authorized to perform: ecs:ListTasks on resource: *”
```

What was needed was to add this statement to the policy:

```
{
     "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": "ecs:ListTasks",
     "Resource": "*"
}
```

Thank you for @Marcin to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using:

```
ecs.list_tasks(cluster='cluster_name')
```

is **correct**. However the error you are getting:

```
not authorized to perform: ecs:ListTasks on resource: *
```

indicates that whichever IAM user/role you are using to run it, has no permissions to `ecs:ListTasks`. Thus you have to double check which user/role is used to execute your script.

Comment: I added a sample policy that the role uses to run the Lambda function. Is there something wrong with it? The `ecs.list_tasks` command works with both `cluster` and `containerInstance` parameters but fails with the `not authorized` error without the `containerInstance` parameter. And in case of Fargate there are no container instances to give to it.

Comment: @Sam The command is fine and it works as expected with fargate. The issue must be somewhere else. Maybe for fargate different permissions are required?